# XMLHTTPRequest over an SSL Connection

Tags: javascript, web-services

I have troubles to call this method:

```
myXmlHttpRequest.send(data);
```

It's because, the Webservice is HTTPS! How to bypass it? In C# I did it, to ignore the SSL-Certificate-Things, but how in JavaScript?

Something like this:

```
objXMLHttpRequest.mozBackgroundRequest = true;
```

gave me an Security Error Code 1000.

Comment: Sounds more like you're violating the same origin policy. JavaScript can only access a web service on the same domain (unless it's a JSONP service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of same origin policy. Javascript wont allow you to hit the webservice. To do a workaround you can write an intermediate proxy to your same server and hit that with xmlhttprequest. The proxy inturn will hit your webservice. As you already mentioned you have done it in c#. Your proxy can be written in that then.